# How to stop showing smartcard selection dialog in NCryptOpenKey from minidriver if key container not available

Tags: c++, cryptography, smartcard, cryptoapi, cng

I am working on a minidriver project which can generate keypair in smartcard.

To generate a keypair from a test application I have to check if there is a keypair exist with the specified container name, if found I have to delete that.

To check if a container exist with the same name I have used ***NCryptOpenKey***

```
Status = NCryptOpenKey(
hProvider,
&hKey,
wszContainerName,
0, // dwLegacyKeySpec
0 // dwFlags
);
```

It works perfectly and returns the key handle if there is a container available in smartcard with my minidriver.

But if there is no keypair with the same label in smart card it shows a dialog like this to select smart card

[image: Select smartcard]

**Is it natural to show the card selection dialog?**

**How to stop showing the card selection dialog from minidriver? NCryptOpenKey can simply return 
SCARD_E_NO_KEY_CONTAINER (0x80100030)**

Comment: Try setting flag NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG

Comment: @plstryagain Thanks. My question was not fully described. The flag is the scope of test application. I want to know if there is any way to stop showing dialog from minidriver. Could you pls provide me any document/link which describes the inner functionality of NCryptOpenKey.

Comment: @iOS-Developer84 I dont actually understand, you call NCryptOpenKey from the driver, why not pass SILENT_FLAG in this driver, If you develop a driver that implements CSP interface, you should handle this flag in the OpenKey routine of this CSP